# How to disable automount of pendrive

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, automount, centos-6

I am using CentOS 6.2 and I want to disable automount of pendrive.

what is the procedure?

which file should I edit?

Answer (score 1):

As root or sudo:

```
/etc/init.d/autofs stop
```

If you don't want it to come back after a reboot, do this as well:

```
chkconfig autofs off
```

Now you will have to mount your devices manually.
Actually this isn't the case on my SL6.3 box, so I was wrong, I guess it has to do with udev.

And Finally here is the answer you probably want:
http://www.tuxradar.com/answers/706

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into the `/etc/fstab` file, and assign the no-auto flag to your drive. I don't know how to comment on your question (which I would do, since this is not a complete answer), but I'll post it here to help out.